# What does ">" mean in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I saw code like this:

```
let items: Array<{
  name: string,
  value: string
} | null> | null
```

What does `null>` mean in this code?

Comment: You are not seeing full picture. it is `Array<{name:string, value:string} | null >` Means an array of object as specified or an array of nulls. Lets call it type T. So, the item is `T | null` means, the item could be T or null. Where T is  an array of object as specified or an array of nulls. Got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the array could hold 2 types. Either holds the specified object containing:

```
name: string,
value: string
```

or it could hold `null` values.